# Generic Типы и двойной UpCast

Tags: c#

всем привет, имеется следующий пример:

```
 public abstract class Shape { }
public class Circle : Shape { }

public interface IContainer<out T>
{
    T Figure { get; }
}

public class Container<T> : IContainer<T>
{
    private T figure;

    public Container(T figure)
    {
        this.figure = figure;
    }

    public T Figure
    {
        get { return figure; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        IContainer<Shape> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);

        Console.WriteLine(container.Figure.ToString());

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

меня интересует вот эта строка

```
IContainer<Shape> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);
```

-экземпляр circle (передаваемый в качестве аргумента конструктора) ни приводится ни к какому типу в данном случае - т.к тип Т (я знаю, что правильно говорить тип места заполнения типом Т, но просто "тип Т" - будет короче) у класса Container мы закрыли тем же типом, что и данный экземпляр (и я имею ввиду, что т.к типы у них одинаковые, то и приводится не к чему.)

Итак, у нас  сперва тип Container приводим к типу IContainer, а поле figure типа Circle приводится к типу Shape.

Почему поле figure внутри класса Container приводится к типу Shape?

итак мои предположения:

1) передаваемый в качестве аргумента экземпляр тут ни причем - т.к как уже было сказанно выше сам экземпляр никчему не приводится.

2)Из-за того, что тип Container мы привели к типу IContainer - тип Т у которого мы закрыли типом Shape

- и отсюда возникает еще один вопрос: у нас одновременно происходит как бы два UpCast -а : Container - IContainer;

Circle-Shape; - какой из них так скажем влияем на передаваемый аргумент конструктора - наш экземпляр circle (да-да, я знаю, что выше писал, что UpCast -a экземпляра circle не происходит - просто в  предыдущем примере экземпляр приводится к типу Shape )

```
IContainer<Shape> container = new Container<Shape>(circle);
```

- но, раз поле figure меняет тип, а ссылка на это поле хранится в этом экземпляре, который мы передаем в качестве аргумента конструктора.

Моя догадка заключается в том, что раз мы тип Т у Container (Circle)  - тот тип которого и аргумент конструктора circle - приводим к типу Т у IContainer(Shape), то и этот аргумент конструктора типа Circle также неявно UpCast - ится "следуя" изменениям своего типа - и соответственно затем произойдет UpCast типов внутри этого экземпляра в том числе и поля figure  - которое изменит свой тип Circle на Shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

У вас в строке `IContainer<Shape> container = new Container<Circle>(circle);` есть лишь одно приведение типов: левая часть имеет тип `IContainer<Shape>`, а правая — `Container<Circle>`.

Почему такое приведение возможно? Дело в `out`, которое у вас в `interface IContainer<out T>`. Смысл этого самого `out` таков: **если `Т1` — подтип `T2`, то `IContainer<T1>` считать подтипом `IContainer<T2>`**.

Таким образом, у вас `Container<Circle>` приводится к `IContainer<Circle>`, а вследствие `out` `IContainer<Circle>` приводится к `IContainer<Shape>`.

То есть при этом реальный тип объекта как был, так и остаётся `Container<Circle>`. То, что к этому объекту *можно получить доступ* по ссылке типа `IContainer<Shape>`, не заставляет тип поля самого объекта поменяться.

---

Почему вообще приведение из `IContainer<Circle>` к `IContainer<Shape>` возможно? Это контролируется компилятором. Дело в том, что тип `T` у вас находится в интерфейсе позиции возвращаемого значения. Это значит, что если у вас реально в руках есть `IContainer<Circle>`, то он *удовлетворяет требованиям* на `IContainer<Shape>`: его свойство `Figure` возвращает объект типа `Circle`, а значит, его можно трактовать как объект типа `Shape`.

(Если бы `T` находилось в позиции аргумента, а не возвращаемого значения, компилятор не дал бы вам скомпилировать интерфейс с `out`.)

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) описание от microsoft. На самом деле, я бы не сильно заострял внимание на этот синтаксический сахар, т.к. для жизни он малую роль играет. Намного важнее понимать что есть generic и как они работают. Суть ссылок. В рихтере хорошо описано, очень подробно, можно глянуть еще там.